# How to add a mouseover/mouseout listener to a ol.Map?

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3

In ol2 I used to use:

```js
map.on( "mouseover mouseout", function( evt ) {...});
```

How can I do this in ol3?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Take a look at this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/CuDYJe?p=preview), there's a lot of other possibilities:

What you ask is done with:

```
map.on('pointermove', function(event) {

});
```

Mouseout:

```
map.getViewport().addEventListener('mouseout', function(evt){
    console.info('out');
}, false);
```

Comment: Thanks Jonatas! Now, how do I know when the pointer has left the map/viewport?